# Why is "to get" sometimes used where "to be" could be used?

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice, past-participles, nuance, get-be

Why is "to get" sometimes used where "to be" could be used? Is this usage grammatical?

Examples:

> - The video got uploaded to the web site.
> - The video was uploaded to the web site.
> - He got thrown in the pool.
> - He was thrown in the pool.
> - We got caught!
> - We were caught!

Comment: If you wanted to search the internet for information, it might be worth knowing that this construction is called the "get-passive".

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock, thanks, I just added "get-passive" to the question title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use forms of *get* instead of forms of *be* as an alternative way to formulate the passive voice. Passive voice clauses constructed with *get* are less formal than those formed with *be*, but otherwise have the same meaning.

However, you can’t use *get* for stative uses of the passive voice, where the passive indicates the result of an action. You can only use it for eventive passives, where the passive indicates an action. Here are examples of the stative passives where *get* is not grammatical:

> 100 votes **are** required to pass the bill
>    * 100 votes **get** required to pass the bill
>
> He **was** rumored to be a war veteran.
>    * He **got** rumored to be a war veteran
>
> The plums **were** intended for breakfast.
>    * The plums **got** intended for breakfast.
>
> A vacuum **is** abhorred by nature.
>    * A vacuum **gets** abhorred by nature.

Answer (score 2):

The usage is correct, if not always formal. Using "to get" puts a more active spin on the result. While the use of "to be" creates a passive-voice construction, the use of "to get" creates an active-voice construction with an implied subject -- that is, it emphasizes that someone specifically caused the action, rather than that it just happened on its own somehow.

Comment: The forms with *get* are passive voice.

Answer (score 1):

This usage is *correct*, but *informal*. It is freely used (and extremely common) in less formal kinds of writing and speaking, but is avoided in the most formal forms of writing.

As for "why", I don't think there is any explanation other than the fact that get + <past participle> is slowly displacing be + <past participle> for the passive construction.

Comment: I don’t think *get* passives are displacing *be* passives; they are just an informal alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**Both forms (i.e. *be* and *get* forms followed by past participle) are grammatically correct.**

> The video got uploaded to the website
>   [by a user].

is passive voice.

> In a sentence using active voice, the
>   subject of the sentence performs the
>   action expressed in the verb.
>   [(source)](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/539/01/)

So, in this case, the subject of the sentence, "the video", wasn't the thing performing the action.  The unnamed user (or whomever performed the action) did.

Comment: +1 for recognizing this as passive. It's very interesting to see English develop a new construction to form it.

Comment: I have a feeling there's still something to be said about *why* it is "get" and not "be". After all, "the video was uploaded to the website [by a user]" would be just as fine.

Comment: -1, because the OP didn't ask for the *meaning* of the construction, but rather its correctness and motivation. (And both of the other answers also implicitly recognized this as passive.)

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  I guess I made an assumption that the OP wasn't simply asking *if*, but also *why* one form is preferred over the other.  I have added a bold typeface to the final conclusion, which answers the question that was explicitly asked.