# How is 'get' being used in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

What grammar structure is this?

1. Bob got/had me drunk.
2. She's got me spending.
3. Get moving!
4. Get going!
5. That music gets/has me dancing!
6. He had/got me stumped.
7. She had/got me stoned.

Is it possible to say: *She has/had me spending?*

Comment: Related: [Why is “to get” sometimes used where “to be” could be used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/why-is-to-get-sometimes-used-where-to-be-could-be-used)

Comment: Hmmm, the structures of my sentences are different than those in the related post.

Comment: Also related: [use 'got' instead of 'was'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37900/use-got-instead-of-was)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got can be used as an [auxiliary verb](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/get?view=uk) meaning

> reach or cause to reach a specified state or condition
>
> - [with object and complement]: I need to get my hair cut
> - [as auxiliary verb] used with past participle to form the passive mood: *the cat got drowned*
> - [with object and past participle] cause to be treated in a specified way: *get the form signed by a doctor* **[got met drunk; [*has*] got me stumped; got me stoned]**
> - [with object and infinitive] induce or prevail upon (someone) to do something: *they got her to sign the consent form*
> - [no object, with infinitive] have the opportunity to do:*he got to try out a few of these nice new cars*
> - [no object, with present participle or infinitive] begin to be or do something, especially gradually or by chance: *we got talking one evening* **[got me spending; get going; gets me dancing]**

While **have** is a much used helping verb, some of your proposed constructions do work and some do not.

OK:

> He had me stumped.
>
> That music has me dancing.
>
> She had me spending [but probably would not be used without additional modifiers, such as *like a drunken sailor*]

Not OK:

> Bob had me drunk.
>
> She had me stoned.

Comment: How should I choose the right verb? Sometimes 'get' is used and sometimes 'have'.

Comment: I do not believe there is a hard and fast rule. There is a good deal of overlap, but the times when one or the other is not appropriate *has [got] me stumped*. It seems idiomatic. If you look at the range of uses for *got* in the cited dictionary, it may give you a feel for when, but I cannot cite a definitive pattern. Practice helps you *get* it.

Answer (score 5):

*Get* and *have* are both auxiliary verbs like *be*, so their choice depends on the constructions they're in. Plus, *get* is related to **both** *be* and *have* -- it's the inchoative verb form for both of these auxiliaries.

*Get* is an [inchoative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51355/15299) verb, originally meaning *come to **have***; therefore it's usable in many constructions with *have*:

- *He has a new car ~ He came to have a new car ~ He got a new car.*
- *He has finished it ~ He has it finished ~ He'll get it finished.*

*Get* **also** means *come to **be*** and is therefore also usable in many *be* constructions.

- *He married her ~ He was married to her ~ He got married to her.*
- *He works on that ~ He is working on that ~ He got working on that.*

*Get* can also, like most inchoatives, be used as a Causative, e.g, *cause to come to be*

- *The wiring is fixed ~ The wiring got fixed ~ He got the wiring fixed.*
- *He is working on that ~ He got working on that ~ I got him going on that.*

That's the source of most of the *get* examples in the original question.

*Have*, however, is another story altogether. There are a number of *have* constructions, including a volitional causative which also works with *get*:

- *He had the floors polished ~ He got the floors polished.*

and a different construction of the same shape that implies bad fortune, and also works with *get*:

- *He had his tires slashed ~ He got his tires slashed.*

and a sense in which it refers to success of a goal, and effectively means *cause* or *make*; *get* works here, also, but requires infinitives **with** *to*.

- *He had us dancing/dance on the table ~ He got us dancing/**to** dance on the table.*
- *I had him see his advisor about that ~ I got him to see his advisor about that.*

Finally, if you can say

- *I am spending*

then you can say

- *She's got me spending*

or

- *She has me spending.*

in any tense of *have* or *get*, if you mean that she is the cause of your spending.

Answer (score 3):

Just one supplement to the excellent answers by John Lawler and bib:

You can't say *He **had** me drunk* because "drunk", although it derives from a verb, is an adjectival use of the participle which no longer has verbal force in ordinary discourse: you would have to construct a very strange story for "He caused somebody to drink me" to be meaningul. You have to say *He **got** me drunk*, meaning "He caused me to become drunk".

The ambiguity of the participle is clearly exposed with *stoned*:

> *He **had** me stoned* means "He caused someone to stone me", that is, to throw stones at me.
>
> *He **got** me stoned* could mean that; but it's more likely to mean "He caused me to become stoned", that is, drug-intoxicated.

Comment: I think it's the possible ambiguity rather than the 'adjective-ness' of the participal / participial that legislates against the example you cite, _He had me drunk_. I'm happy with _He had me drunk / tipsy by 9:30_, and with _He had me convinced_ (where _convinced_ is obviously an adjectival, rather than a participle usage meaning _He got people to convince me_).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  A good point. Would you find it more accurate if I distinguished between *passive* and *perfective* uses of the participle?

Comment: There is perhaps, one other exception to your rejection of *He **had** me drunk*. The phrase *had me* can be used to refer to a sexual relationship that might logically fit. See Carly Simon's *He's So Vain* lyrics "You **had me** several years ago, when I was still quite naive . . . " In this example, it would mean *He had me [while I was ] drunk*. Obviously, this would require context to make sense.

Comment: @bib  Or of course it could bear the sense *[while he was] drunk*.

Comment: @StoneyB True. Or even *He had me [while we both were] drunk.*

Comment: @bib   Or even [gasp!] *[while the whole lot of us were] drunk*.

Comment: Okay, +1 already!

Comment: The 'cause/make' _have_ construction that I mention above can work that way with _drunk_; example in next comment.

Comment: _The night before the wedding, they started the party at 7 pm and had him drunk by 10; after that he wouldn't stop dancing until 3._

Comment: @JohnLawler  That's a very good one to worry on. It's obviously right; but equally, nobody says *They had him drunk so they could steal his wallet*. I've got a dim sense that it's analogous to *Doing that will get* (not have) *me arrested.* How would you account for this difference in usage?

Comment: @StoneyB I think that's the same _have_ as in _I have it fixed_, and it indicates some duration of effort with the stated result. So as long as you indicate a duration, it works: _By midnight, they had him drunk so they could steal his wallet_.